# Xcode wants to use _bridge to close sqlite3 database

Tags: objective-c, xcode4, sqlite

Though I have linked the sqlite3 framework and included the headers in my application delegate file, Xcode wants to change:

```
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application
{
    if ([MyDatabase database]) sqlite3_close([MyDatabase database]);

}
```

to this:

```
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application
{
    if ([MyDatabase database]) sqlite3_close((__bridge sqlite3 *)([MyDatabase database]));

}
```

In the code above, database is a singleton reference to an instance of MyDatabase that works in all other aspects of the program.

Comment: You can't pass an instance of `MyDatabase*` to `sqlite3_close`. It requires your `sqlite3*` handle.

Comment: Interesting...I can make a private method in the database controller that will close it,  - (void) close_db {
    sqlite3_close(_database);
}, but making that method a public one results in the same request to add _bridge.  How can I access the handle outside of the instanciating class?

Comment: Either use a -close method on your class, or expose a method which returns the internal `_database` variable (of type `sqlite*`)